# RN FlatList with Typescript and Styled Components

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

SO community,

I can't figure out the correct type definition for an RN FlatList styled with Styled Components in Typescript

So I have type `IProduct` like that

```
interface IProduct {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

and I define the types for the `FlatList` like that

```
<FlatList
  data={products}
  renderItem={({ item }: { item: IProduct }) => (
    <SomeComponent item={item} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item: IProduct) => item.id}
/>
```

everything works fine. Typescript does not complain but as soon as I want to style the `FlatList` like that

```
const StyledFlatList = styled.FlatList`
  background-color: 'white';
`;

<StyledFlatList
  data={products}
  renderItem={({ item }: { item: IProduct }) => (
    <SomeComponent item={item} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item: IProduct) => item.id}
/>
```

I get lots of Typescript errors

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof FlatList, DefaultTheme, {}, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof FlatList, DefaultTheme, {}, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.
    Type '({ item }: { item: IProduct; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ListRenderItem<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof FlatList, DefaultTheme, {}, never>): 
ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof FlatList, DefaultTheme, {}, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.
    Type '(item: IProduct) => string' is not assignable to type '(item: unknown, index: number) => string'.ts(2769)

index.d.ts(4218, 5): The expected type comes from property 'keyExtractor' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<FlatListProps<unknown> & RefAttributes<FlatList<unknown>>, "ref" | "data" | "style" | "ItemSeparatorComponent" | ... 141 more ... | "key"> & Partial<...>, "ref" | ... 144 more ... | "key"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'

index.d.ts(4218, 5): The expected type comes from property 'keyExtractor' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<FlatListProps<unknown> & RefAttributes<FlatList<unknown>>, "ref" | "data" | "style" | "ItemSeparatorComponent" | ... 141 more ... | "key"> & Partial<...>, "ref" | ... 144 more ... | "key"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'
```

Can someone tell me how to fix that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few trial and error runs I think I found a solution that works but it's not ideal.

```
<StyledFlatList<any>
  data={products}
  renderItem={({ item }: { item: IProduct }) => (
    <ProductCard product={item} onProductPress={handleOnProductPress} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item: IProduct) => item.id}
/>
```

Let me know if that looks OK with you.

**UPDATE 1:**

If I add the code snippet [Ben Clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228109/ben-clayton) suggested, prettier will format the code like that

```
const StyledFlatList = (styled.FlatList`
  background-color: ${colors.silver};
` as unknown) as FlatList;
```

and I get a TS error

```
JSX element type 'StyledFlatList' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Instead of `<any>` I tried `<React.ElementType>` as suggested [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28631) which seems to work too.

```
<StyledFlatList<React.ElementType>
  data={products}
  renderItem={({ item }: { item: IProduct }) => (
    <ProductCard product={item} onProductPress={handleOnProductPress} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item: IProduct) => item.id}
/>
```

Comment: i don't have an IDE handy but TypeScript should 'know' the type of item already, so you should be able to omit all the type information from the renderItem and keyExtractor params. e.g. `renderItem={ ({ item }) => (` `keyExtractor={item => `.

Comment: Yes, I thought exactly the same. Unfortunately, it doesn't. As I mentioned before, if I use RN FlatList TS doesn't complain and infers the type but it complains when I use styled-components, although I have `@types/styled-components` installed.

Comment: ah - yes I see. I remember this one from a couple years back, we ran into just the same thing. what if you define `const StyledFlatList = styled.FlatList'
  background-color: 'white';
' as unknown as FlatList`.  E.g. make TS think StyledFlatList is just a 'plain' FlatList?

Comment: Btw, can you elaborate on the syntax? `const StyledFlatList = styled(FlatList)'
  background-color: ${colors.silver}; 
' as unknown as FlatList` doesn't work

Comment: sure sorry I couldn't put the correct syntax in the comment... try putting `as unknown as FlatList` after the declaration of `StyledFlatList`. This forces TS to think that StyledFlatList is of type FlatList.

Comment: Hi @BenClayton, I have added an update below because it formats better. I get a new TS error now `JSX element type 'StyledFlatList' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Answer (score 17):

Looks like adding `typeof` to another suggested solution solved this in a more straightforward way, even allowing you to exclude types from props:

```
const StyledFlatList = (styled.FlatList`
  background-color: 'white';
` as unknown) as typeof FlatList;

<StyledFlatList
  data={products}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <SomeComponent item={item} />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
/>
```

Comment: ```const StyledFlatList = styled.FlatList`
                                          background-color: 'white';
` as typeof FlatList;```
Works as well

Answer (score 6):

This simple solution works for me:

```
interface IProduct {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

const StyledFlatList = styled(FlatList as new () => FlatList<IProduct>)`
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
`
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to inform the generic type with, styled.FlatList``

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const StyledFlatList = styled.FlatList<IProduct>`
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me, after some tests (and mergin the sugestions on this topic):

At styles.ts, my typed FlatList ended like this:

```
 export const CustomFlatList = styled(FlatList as typeof FlatList<EstablishmentTransactionAntecipationDTO>)`
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom styled-components `FlatList` type that accepts `IProduct` as follows:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { FlatList, FlatListProps } from 'react-native';
import IProduct from './Product.d';

export const StyledFlatList = styled(FlatList as new (props: FlatListProps<IProduct>) => FlatList<IProduct>)`
  // your styles
`;
```

Then use it in your `.tsx`

```
<StyledFlatList
  data={products}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <SomeComponent item={item} />}
  keyExtractor={(item: IProduct) => item.id}
/>
```